# Sincronização de Repositório - GIT

Tags: git, github, sincronização

Bem, estou trabalhando em um projeto na faculdade e tive alguns problemas sobre o uso do git na hora de sincronizar um repositório. Mais precisamente, eu recebi as seguintes instruções de uso:

- A branch Master é a principal e jamais deverá receber um push/pull request de teste/desnecessário/irresponsável.
- Antes de mais nada, atualize o repositório. Lembrando que o seu fork não está automaticamente sincronizado com o projeto.
- Sempre atualize o seu repositório antes de começar a codar e sempre mantenha o seu código o mais atualizado possível para evitar conflitos.

Eu segui alguns tutoriais na internet de sincronização como por exemplo o que o próprio github disponibiliza (para os interessados: https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/#platform-linux), mas quase todos estão em inglês, o que dificulta até certo ponto o meu entendimento (até com as traduções acaba ficando um pouco difícil de entender ) e poucos explicam realmente como eu faço para sincronizar o MEU repositório que foi "forkado" com o repositório PRINCIPAL do projeto. Alguém pode me ajudar ou me dar algum caminho para seguir? Vale ressaltar que eu uso o Linux. Desde já, agradeço. :)

Comment: Para manter o seu projeto atualizado, basta clonar o repositório do `git` na sua maquina, ele traz o status atual do projeto atualizado....
Toda vez que você ligar a sua maquina, e for começar alterar o projeto, sincronize, isso puxa todas as atualizações, `branchs` criadas e `commits` realizados por outras pessoas no repositório.
Caso algum dia por alguma razão veja que existem muitos arquivos diferentes no seu ambiente de trabalho, arquivos com alterações que nao foram suas, basta remover da sua maquina a pasta, e clonar o repositório do `git` novamente.

Comment: Só mais uma dica: Os comandos do `git` são os mesmos tanto pra `linux`, quanto pra 'windows', eu uso a versão gráfica do `windows` e nunca tive nenhum problema, pessoas que vem do universo `Linux` veem mais facilidade em trabalhar com a versão `Git shell`, que esta disponível em ambos os ambientes também.

Comment: Então, nós estamos trabalhando com repositórios diferentes, e eu tenho sempre que sincronizar o MEU repositório com o repositório PRINCIPAL de onde eu "forkei". Ao meu ver, ficar deletando e clonando o repositório acaba sendo visto como "gambiarra", já que existem processos que foram criados justamente para facilitar a solução desse problema. Eu quero justamente saber quais comandos ou procedimentos eu devo tomar para "otimizar" a minha produção.

Comment: `fork` no meu entendimento trabalhando com a ferramenta, são justamente os `branchs` que se diferem do `branch Master`, apos você fazer todos os `commits`, e der um `push` ou `publish`, voce deve dar um `merge` no `branch` para que sua `branch` seja incluida no `branch master`, caso o dono do repositório, ou você mesmo venha a desconsiderar o `branch`, basta remover o mesmo que nao afeta em nada o estado do `branch master`

Comment: A intenção não é essa, de ficar deletando e clonando hausahsuh o ideal é só dar um `sync` que o projeto na sua maquina estará atualizado, contanto que esteja com uma conexão da internet, ele já baixa os arquivos que não tiverem na sua maquina, essa artimanha de remover da maquina e clonar novamente, é so caso veja que tem alguma coisa errada (Tipo 3 pessoas trabalhando no mesmo projeto, ter um ambiente de homologação, um de produção, e o `github` pra controle de versionamento, as vezes se a equipe não se comunica, pode ocorrer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu estou supondo que vc já instalou o GIT na sua máquina local e já tem uma ideia de como ele funciona. Se vc já fez o fork, agora deve clonar o projeto pra sua máquina. Tem um botão verde no canto superior direito do projeto que vc clica e ele copia o link: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida, entre no diretório onde o projeto vai ficar, digite o comando: `git clone` seguido do link copiado do projeto:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A seguir, entre no diretório criado (no caso Spoon-Knife) e as operações são basicamente essas:

**Para atualizar o seu repositório local:**

1. `git fetch`: recupera as alterações feitas no servidor remoto;
2. `git pull`: baixa todas as alterações remotas para o seu repositório local;

**Para enviar suas alterações locais para o repositório remoto:**

3. `git add -A`
4. `git commit -a -m "Descrição" -m "Detalhamento do commit"`

Todas essas informações estão [aqui](https://help.github.com/articles/fetching-a-remote/). Tutorial bacana [aqui](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html).

Comment: Sua resposta me ajudou muito...

Comment: Sua resposta me ajudou muito...
Uma pergunta, o que é melhor, fork ou clone ??
Neste caso onde o curso disponibilize um git para o material e este material possa ser alterado, seria melhor fork ou clone ?

Comment: @FabioAragão, em termos bem genéricos, a diferença básica entre `fork` e `clone` é que, no `fork`, vc permanece linkado ao conteúdo original, podendo contribuir com o código/desenvolvimento. Quando vc faz o `clone`, a sua cópia do código é independente do repositório original. Se vc não pretende contribuir com o desenvolvimento, então prefira `clone`. Basicamente é isso.